# html5 video performance issue Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

I'm having some problems with html5 video in Internet Explorer 10 (and probable 9 and 11 as well).

The problem is that I'm playing multiple video's at the same time. In Firefox and Chrome there's no problem. In IE at first also no problem. The problem comes when I start scrolling. Then the video's get scrambled up and the timing isn't good anymore.

Are there ways to improve the performance of IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE 10 or less i've created a different page with animated gif. IE11 and other browsers have better performance with html5 video.

Thanks a lot Microsoft, took me a couple of hours to debug this!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can really do anything here. The more videos you add the slower it will be - sooner or later in Firefox and Chrome as well.

You will likely reach better performance by using the old-fashioned `<object>` tag for embedding Windows Media files, however that is outdated and will only work in IE properly.

What you could do is to check via JavaScript which videos are actually "visible" for the user (I assume that a user does not see every video as soon as he starts scrolling, he might see two/three of them but not more) and pause/remove the videos that are currently not visible. You can dynamically include them later on once the user scrolls back. This will certainly improve performance on all browsers.

**EDIT**

So you don't need any sound. GIFs are even more outdated, but hey, they even work on mobile devices.

Probably Silverlight is an option, there's still the Expression Encoder that will convert the video and give you a decent default player:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=18974

Maybe worth a try, at least it should make proper use of hardware acceleration. But also outdated and will not work on mobile devices.

Another idea: always use the "Simple" encoding profile and a low resolution/frame rate. This will harm quality, but will still be much better than GIFs and takes much less CPU power on decoding. Depending on your encoding tool you will be able to configure this for H.264 and VC-1 video codec. Give it a try.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks for the reply. All the video's need to play at the same time because there is interaction between the video's. All the video's can be visible on one page, so it's not posible to only play the video on visible elements. I think i'm going to try the <object> tag. Will let you know if it worked.

Comment: Hi Jan, I've tried converting all the video's to wmv and used the old-fashion way to show then on the webpage. It's still quite slow, but it performs better then html5 video. I'm thinking about using animated gif for IE. The files are bigger then WMV. Do you know if animated gif needs better performance then WMV? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've made the page with animated gifs. There are 21 on one page. The page is loaded properly when i use 10 fps. With 15 fps the page still has very poor performance. Keep up the good work microsoft, ahum!

Comment: Updated my answer with some more dieas/suggestions

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for sharing your ideas, I'm out of time to continue developping the page, it works fine with animated gif. Excellent idea to use silverlight, i'll give it a try on the next project :)